# DateTime.ParseExact with varible fraction of seconds

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

I have to parse time given in hours, minutes, seconds and fraction of seconds. Such as

```
"15:42:58.1"
"15:42:58.21"
"15:42:58.417"
```

using the following code:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("15:42:58.1", "HH:mm:ss.0.f", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This works with excactly one decimal. Any other nomber of decimal will cause an exception.

Question:

- Is there a generic possibility for the number of decimals of seconds?

Comment: There is no month and year etc. Is this better modelled as a `TimeSpan`?

Comment: [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String___System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_) has an overload that accepts an array of formats.

Comment: `HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFF` will work for any number of fractional digits up to 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TimeSpan` if this is a time of day or similar. See [Custom TimeSpan format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings). The trick from Jeroen Mostert's comment to your question still applies: Use capital `F`s.

You must escape the delimiters with `TimeSpan` format strings. Therefore, use one of:

```
var ts1 = TimeSpan.ParseExact("15:42:58.1", @"hh\:mm\:ss\.FFFFFFF", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var ts2 = TimeSpan.ParseExact("15:42:58.1", "hh':'mm':'ss'.'FFFFFFF", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This appears to work even with trailing zeros, e.g. `"15:42:58.10"` parses OK.

---

EDIT: Since 2021 (.NET 6), you can also pick the `TimeOnly` struct. It represent a time-of-day without any date (whereas `TimeSpan` represents a positive or negative amount of time that could span several days, yes, even thousands of days).

Answer (score 2):

You can use array of DateTimeFormat.
like

```
string[] validFormats = { "HH:mm:ss.f", "HH:mm:ss.ff", "HH:mm:ss.fff" };
DateTime.ParseExact("15:42:58.1", validFormats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Now this will parse your `DateTime`, even if you fraction of 3 digits

[.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SOUUNI)

Comment: The fiddle writes `9/27/2019 3:42:58 PM`. I suppose the fiddle will return a different string if I try it on another day than September 27. Does the asker want the current date to "leak" into his parsed value?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, I updated my fiddle, now it will show only Time string. `.ToLongTimeString()`