# AWS Lambda Json Serializer is removing trailing zeros from milliseconds in a date time input

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, asp.net-core-3.1

I have created an AWS lambda with C# .net core 3.1. This lambda takes a json object as input and one of the property names of the json object is a datetime. Look below for example input

```
{
    "datetime": "2022-05-10T11:49:21.120Z",
    "context": {
        "user": "{\"Id\": \"user_id\"}"
    }
}
```

C# lambda handler:

```
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]
namespace LambdaFunction
{
    public class Function
    {
        public async Task<JObject> FunctionHandler(JObject event, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine("Event Details: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(event));
            string dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'";
            var dateString = JToken.ReadFrom(jr)["AsOfDatetime"].ToString();
            if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dateValue))
            {
                throw new Exceptopm("datetime is not in UTC format");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I logged the input event inside the lambda and it printed the below value

```
{
    "datetime": "2022-05-10T11:49:21.12Z",
    "context": {
        "user": "{\"Id\": \"user_id\"}"
    }
}
```

The trailing `0` in datetime key's milliseconds before `Z` (representing UTC) got removed `2022-05-10T11:49:21.120Z` to `2022-05-10T11:49:21.12Z`. I am trying to validate the input date time using `DateTime.TryParse` as in the above code. But because the serializer is removing the trailing zeros and I'm using `.fff` in the format, it's throwing error even when I give correct input if the input datetime has trailing zeros. I am going to later on store this date time in database and I want to store milliseconds to exactly 3 decimals. So, how can I prevent the serializer from removing the trailing zeros?

I'm sure we can write some code to add zeros at the end and achieve what we want but it just seems like extra work. Why do the trailing zeros even get removed by the serializer?

Comment: There is nothing to "fix" - **trailing zeroes are insignificant**. What is your _actual_ problem?

Comment: "and one of the keys of the json object is a date time value" <-- Property names are keys, not property values.

Comment: @Dai I've updated the question with more details

Comment: Your test date and its printout are 9 days apart. Seems odd.

Comment: @jarmod that was just a mistake I made when I wrote the question. I've updated it.

Comment: For reference, the docs say: "The format of the string representation must match a specified format exactly or an exception is thrown." You've specified `.fffZ`, so I presume it's expecting 3 digits. Some possible solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58135499/datetime-parseexact-with-varible-fraction-of-seconds).